# How do I find and replace a duplicate number in a string and keep one of the duplicate numbers?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, replace

I am using Visual Basic 2010

I am trying to find a specific duplicate number in a string and replace it with another number but keep one of the duplicates in the string. For example: the string is `24828` and i need the new string to be `24628` which keeps one of the 8's and the other 8 is replaced by 6. In my code I have it replacing both 8's and result is `24626`. It is replacing both 8's with 6's. Can anyone help? Note: There are two duplicate numbers in this example but the specific duplicate I need is the 8 and not the 2. Also, it does not matter which 8 is replaced or kept. Thank you! Update to this post... The 5 digit string will not always be `24828`. I am using this string as an example. There could even be a string that does not have any 8's at all. I need to check any string that has more than one 8. If it has one 8 then the string does not need to change.

```
Dim strText As String = "24828"
Dim newStrText As String = ""
Dim nIndex = strText.IndexOf("8")
If nIndex > -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Found 8")
    newStrText = strText.Replace("8", "6")
    MessageBox.Show(newStrText)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("There is no 8")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works nicely:

```
Dim text = "24828"

Dim split = text.Split("8"c)
Dim result = If(split.Length > 1, _
    String.Join("6", split.Take(split.Length - 1)) + "8" + split.Last(), _
    text)
```

I get `24628`.

Comment: wow that is exactly what i needed. i tried every string possible and it just works works works. thank you so much Enigmativity :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim OldText As String = "24828"
Dim NewText As String = OldText.Replace("4828","4628")
```

Comment: i am sorry... i guess i should have stated that the 5 digit numbers in the string can be different numbers from time to time. My example has the Else MessageBox.Show("There is no 8") which means sometimes the 5 digit number may not even have any 8's. I need the string to check each digit and see if any of them is an 8. if there is an 8 then also check if there are more 8's. if so replace the 8 with a 6 except to always leave one 8 in the string if there are more than one 8 in the string. Hope that makes sense now. Again, I am sorry for not being more clear about what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s = "24828"
Dim i = s.IndexOf("8")
If i >= 0 Then
    Mid(s, i + 1, 1) = "6"        ' "24628"
End If
```

or

```
Dim s = "24828"
Dim s2 = Join(Split(s, "8", 2), "6")  ' "24628"
```

Actually, the `Replace` method has a `Count` parameter to limit the number of replaces:

```
Dim s = "24828"
Dim s3 = Replace(s, "8", "6",  , 1)   ' "24628"
```

**Update**

I did not read the whole question. To count the number of `8`'s :

```
Dim s = "24828"
Dim count = Split(s, "8").Length - 1      ' 2
```

to find all duplicate characters in the string:

```
Dim s = "24828"
Dim dupliates = (From d In s Group By d Into g = Group Where g.Count > 1 Select d).ToArray  ' { "2"c, "8"c }
```

or to find the indexes of the duplicate characters:

```
Dim s = "24828"
Dim dupliateIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, Len(s)).GroupBy(Function(i) s(i)).SelectMany(Function(g) g.Skip(1)).ToArray  ' { 3, 4 }
```